# Help with math notation (noob question)

Tags: notation

I'm teaching myself math and I can't figure out what the below symbols mean in a textbook:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I did figure out that $\Bbb Z$ = integer set and $\Bbb N$ = natural, and $\Bbb R$ = real. But what do all the pluses and dots and $\{0\}$ mean? Eg how is the first $\Bbb Z$ different from the second?

Broader question - what book / tutorial exists that can help me get comfortable with notation?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Every book has its own notation, and while most of it is conventional, any good book also _explains_ any notation they use. Are you sure that these aren't explained wherever you have these from?

Comment: $(\mathbb Z, +)$ is the *structure* of *integers* with the only operation of *addition* while $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$ is the *structure* of *integers* with the only operation of *multiplication*.

Comment: $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is the ordered pair whose first element is the set of integers and whose second element is the addition operation on the integers. $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$ is the ordered pair whose first element is the set of integers and whose second element is the multiplication operation on the integers. $(\mathbb R^n,+)$ is the ordered pair whose first element is $\mathbb R^n$ (that is, the set of all ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers) and whose second element is the addition operation on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: The `+` and `·` refer to the algebraic operation  on the set: addition or multiplication. For instance $(\Bbb Z,+)$ means  one considers the set of integers, endowed with addition.

Comment: Notation varies from author to author. You'll pick up the standard notation over time, and many books have an index listing the notation they use. For your question, a bit of context would be useful, but it looks like your book is considering algebraic structures. For example, the notation $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is commonly used to indicate that the integers are considered as a group with the group operation being addition. The notation $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ is less common, since the integers don't form a group with multiplication, but it could be a monoid. That's why context would be useful.

Comment: I think your last "broader question" is the right question. What book are you reading now? And say a little more about your math background (there's nothing in your profile). In his 1950 book "Measure Theory", Halmos wrote in the preface... _The reader should not be discouraged if he finds that he does not have the prerequisites to read the prerequisites._ Glad to see you're taking his advice, still very good advice seventy years later.

Answer (score 3):

- $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is the set $\mathbb Z$ endowed with the operation addition;
- $(\mathbb Z,\cdot)$ is the set $\mathbb Z$ endowed with the operation multiplication;
- $(\mathbb N_0,+)$ is the set $\mathbb N_0$ endowed with the operation addition;
- $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\neq0\}$;
- $(\mathbb R^n,+)$ is the set $\mathbb R^n$ endowed with the operation addition;
- $(\mathbb Z^n,+)$ is the set $\mathbb Z^n$ endowed with the operation addition.

Comment: Also note that $X^n$ in this context means the cartesian product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of $n$ copies of $X$

Comment: Some people denote $\Bbb N_0$ by $\Bbb N$, i.e., the set $\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol represent

- $(\mathbb Z,+)$ a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) on integer numbers by sum
- $(\mathbb Z,\cdot)$ a group on integer numbers by product
- $(\mathbb N,+)$ a structure on natural numbers by sum
- $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is the set of real numbers without the zero element (indeed the symbol "$\setminus$" indicates the subtraction for sets)
- $n\in \mathbb N$ means that $n$ belongs to the set of natural numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes of course! I fix that

Comment: Careful, $(\Bbb N,+)$ is not a group, because $n\ge 1$ has no additive inverse.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You are right! I'll use structure for that.